# returns long double instead of double

Tags: double, long-double

I am writing a program in c++ where I want to find the epsilon of my pc.
I want the result to be double precision (which is 2.2204460492503131 E-16) but instead the output is 1.0842 E-019 which is the epsilon in long double precision.

My program is this:

```
#include <iostream>

double e = 1.0;
double x;

int main () 
{

    for (int i = 0; e + 1.0!=1.0 ; i++)
    {
        std::cout<<e<<'\n';
        x = e;
        e/=2.0;
    }

    std::cout << "The epsilon of this Computer is "<< x <<'\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Output `std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()` instead.   `std::numeric_limits` is declared in the standard header `<limits>`.

A more usual technique, if you really must calculate it (rather than trusting your standard library to provide a correct value) is

```
double epsilon = 1.0;

while ((1.0 + 0.5 * epsilon) != 1.0)
    epsilon *= 0.5;
```

or to do the calculation.

Note that (although you haven't shown how you did it) it may actually be your `long double` calculation that is incorrect, since literal floating point values (like `1.0`) default to being of type `double`, not `long double` - which might suggest the error is in your calculation of the `long double` result, not the `double` one..   If you want the result to be of type `long double`, it would be advisable to give all of that literal values (`1.0`, `0.5`) the `L` suffix, to force them to be of type `long double`.

Also remember to use appropriate formatting when streaming the resultant value to `std::cout`, to ensure output also has the accuracy/precision you need.   The default settings (what you get if you don't control the formatting) may differ.